# how to force a window to the foreground created by a JNI call

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, window, foreground

I have a Java app that fires a JNI command off to a C++ dll that creates a Win32 for me.  I'd like this window to appear on top of my Java application when this happens however no matter what I try, the C++ generated window always appears under my java app window.

I tried calling `SetForegroundWindow` and  `AllowSetForegroundWindow` from my dll but that doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas on what else I could try?  I feel like I have to tell the Java app to free itself somehow, to allow the other window to come on the top.

Comment: Have you tried calling, after `SetForegroundWindow()`, the function `SetActiveWindow()`?

Comment: Yes,  that doesn't work